# regular expression @ character in word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I am trying to extract words that starts with `@` from a `string`

I created a simple `regex` using `word boundary`. But it is not finding matches when I try to find match words starts with `@` character. I tried to escape character with `\` but no use of it. Somebody please help me

```
const str='@alice wants to meet @bob'
console.log(str.match(/(\b@\S+\b)/ig))
```

Above code returns `null`

Comment: Under what circumstances exactly do you want to match `@`? Do you want to ensure that what comes before is not a word character, or what?

Comment: I would like to extract words that starts with `@` symbol in order to identify users by username

Comment: So do you mean that `foo@bar` should not match?

Comment: yeah exactly. Only words staring with `@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to ensure that the location between the `@` and the previous character is *not* a word boundary (since a word boundary would indicate that the previous character was a word character) - this can be matched with `\B`, which matches everywhere `\b` doesn't:

```js
const str='@alice wants to meet @bob foo@bar'
console.log(str.match(/\B@\S+\b/ig))
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot!. What is differnce bw using `\b` and `\B`

Comment: `\b` matches a word boundary, while `\B` matches everywhere that is not a word boundary